# Unable to check exception type in google test

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

I'm unable to check the exception throw by my code in `gtests`. Here's a snippet of the test suite which runs the test:

```
EXPECT_THROW({
        try{
            // Insert a tuple with more target columns than values
            rows_changed = 0;
            query = "INSERT INTO test8(num1, num3) VALUES(3);";

            txn = txn_manager.BeginTransaction();
            plan = TestingSQLUtil::GeneratePlanWithOptimizer(optimizer, query, txn);
            EXPECT_EQ(plan->GetPlanNodeType(), PlanNodeType::INSERT);
            txn_manager.CommitTransaction(txn);
            TestingSQLUtil::ExecuteSQLQueryWithOptimizer(
                optimizer, query, result, tuple_descriptor, rows_changed, error_message);
            }
        catch (CatalogException &ex){
            EXPECT_STREQ("ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions", ex.what());
            }
  }, CatalogException);
```

I'm pretty sure that `CatalogException` is thrown. I even tried getting the details of the thrown exception by outputting it to `cerr`, and it showed `Exception Type: Catalog`.

This is not a duplicate question, I searched for answers on SO and I'm *not* using `new` in my code which throws the error. Here's the snippet which does that:

```
if (columns->size() < tup_size)
      throw CatalogException(
          "ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns");
```

Finally, here's the definition of `CatalogException`:

```
class CatalogException : public Exception {
  CatalogException() = delete;

 public:
  CatalogException(std::string msg) : Exception(ExceptionType::CATALOG, msg) {}
};
```

Comment: The `catch` catches the exception and it is not thrown again in the catch block, so where do the exception come from?

Comment: @TobiasWollgam It comes from the last code block I mentioned, which is in a different file. The code from that file is executed in the `try` block.

Comment: But the catch block 'consumes' the exception. After that the exception is gone.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam But then the test suite should say that nothing is thrown, but it says that an exception of another type is thrown.

Comment: Ah, ok. So the type of the exception is `Catalog`?

Comment: Yes, that's what gets printed to `cerr`. In my code, only one type of exception can print that: `CatalogException` (that's the name of the exception class).

Comment: @TobiasWollgam See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The idea from `EXPECT_THROW` is, that the macro catches the exception. If you catch the exception by yourself, gmock don't now anything about a thrown exception.

I suggest to just write the statement into the `EXPECT_THROW`, which actually trigger the exception. Everything else can be written before.

For example:

```
 TEST(testcase, testname) 
 {
  //arrange everything:
  //...
  //act + assert:
  EXPECT_THROW(TestingSQLUtil::ExecuteSQLQueryWithOptimizer( optimizer, query, result,
   tuple_descriptor, rows_changed, error_message)
   ,CatalogException);
}
```

I assume, that `TestingSQLUtil::ExecuteSQLQueryWithOptimizer` is trigger the thrown exception.

**addition:**
I tried to rebuild your exception hierarchy. This example works for me very well. The test passes, which means the exception is thrown.

```
enum class ExceptionType
{
    CATALOG
};

class Exception {
public:
    Exception(ExceptionType type, std::string msg) {}
};

class CatalogException : public Exception {
    CatalogException() = delete;

public:
    CatalogException(std::string msg)  : Exception(ExceptionType::CATALOG, msg) {}
};

void testThrow() {
    throw CatalogException( "ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns");
}

TEST(a,b) {
    EXPECT_THROW( testThrow(), CatalogException);
}
```